# Reference JavaScript code elements in IDEA (WebStorm, PhpStorm, ...)

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, plugins, ide, development-environment

There is a useful feature in IDEA PhpStorm to reference code element (const, class, method):

[image]

Result: `\Monolog\Processor\GitProcessor::$level`

Does any similar method exist to reference JavaScript code elements? I have only name of the variable or function, w/o placement pointer to project scripts hierarchy - `setPrototypeOf`.

Desirable result is smth. like `node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js::setPrototypeOf`.

May be some IDEA plugin provides this ability?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript/TypeScript, **Copy reference** action copies full qualified name to clipboard. For example, for `bar()` method below it would be `myNamespace.MyInterface.bar`:

```
declare namespace myNamespace {
  interface MyInterface {
    bar():void;
  }
}
```

for object key, like:

```
const Obj = {
  key: ()=> {}
}
```

it's `Obj.key`. Similar results can be obtained using **Copy qualified name to clipboard** action in [breadcrumbs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.2/settings-editor-breadcrumbs.html) right-click menu.

There is, however, no way to prepend this value with a file path. You need using **Copy relative path** action in file right-click menu to copy a path to clipboard

Comment: `myNamespace.MyInterface.bar` would be great, unfortunately I use pure JS, w/o TypeScript capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I use `@namespace` & `@memberOf` JSDoc annotations:

```js
/**
 * @namespace Monolog_Processor
 */
"use strict";

/**
 *
 * @memberOf Monolog_Processor
 * @constructor
 */
function GitProcessor() {
    this.$level = 16;
}

module.exports = GitProcessor;
```

This is the reference: `Monolog_Processor.GitProcessor.$level`